# Practical reasons for Church Encoding

Tags: haskell, church-encoding

Church encoding (aka Visitor Pattern) is a way of representing data as functions: instead of

```
data T = C1 F1 F2 | C2 F3 F4
```

you can define

```
data T = T (forall r. (F1 -> F2 -> r) -> (F3 -> F4 -> r) -> r)
```

. Although the ability to represent anything as a function is nice, I've always thought the first version was preferable because it's cleaner and it does not require language extensions (explicit `forall`). However, you can sometimes find church-encoded data in public libraries. What are the advantages of using that?

The examples of church encoding in public libraries:

- [Iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/iteratee/0.8.8.1/doc/html/Data-Iteratee-Base.html#t%3aIteratee)
- [Revision control monad](https://github.com/ekmett/revisions/blob/master/Control/Concurrent/Revision/Monad.hs#L58)
- (please help me extend the list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This corresponds to [*continuation-passing style*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) with multiple continuations, and is done for performance: the explicit construction and destruction of data is avoided, instead passing control *directly* based on the output of the pattern-match that would be immediately done instead. This doesn't always result in improved performance, but when it does it can be fairly significant.

Basically, you can think of it as *data vs. control*. If what you're doing is essentially similar to control in nature — such as the success and failure branches of a parser — then the control-based representation might well be superior. Otherwise, stick with data.